# Do we stil really need @file or @since JavaDoc tags?

Tags: java, javadoc

Do you use @since or @file JavaDoc tags in your *.java files? For me these tags are really obsolete nowadays.

@file: 
What is the benefit? If I want to find a file I use the "Open Resource" feature of my IDE and type the classname. The @file tag is just the repetition of the classname.

@since
There is absolutely no benefit. For what do we have version control systems?
(It makes sense for libraries but I especially talk about projects)

What do you think?

Comment: Personally I agree on the 'file' tag, however I do still use 'since' for self developed libraries that are used in various projects in the company. These files can't be efficiently traced with version control but I still feel it necessary to document author, content and time of change. That beeing said I am afraid the the community rather likes problem related questions in this section and less discussions about opinions.

Comment: For me there is no doubt that the author tag makes absolutely sense. You should generate automatically the JavaDoc for each deployed version of your library. This means you and your library users are able to clearly track everything.

Answer (score 5):

Annotations in JavaDoc are not for the developer, which develops a library. These Informations are for developer which uses this libraries and they have no Access to your version control System or to the source project.

Comment: You should anyway generate the JavaDoc for each deployed version of your library. This means you and your library users are able to clearly track everything.

Comment: @user6444340 Sorry i do not understand what you would say. But yes a javadoc belongs to every version of a library

Comment: I especially talk about the @since tag. In my opinion it is obsolete because you are able to track every method in the respective javadoc if you want to find out the first occurence.

Comment: @user6444340 you do not want to read every javadoc if you use an API. Do you want to read all javadocs to see in which Spring Version a class was introduced?

Comment: Ok, thats an argument. Than I would agree it makes sense for libraries. But for a project I still think it is absolutely obsolete.

Comment: @user6444340 Maybe. It is not a must to use it. It is a can.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that Spring do not use it consistently
 
.

Comment: @user6444340 I can not agree. But normaly it depends on the programmer

Answer (score 2):

Especially the @since annotation can be very useful when trying to find out since which version of a library a method has been available.
There are plenty of examples in the JDK API docs for example. Very handy when you are trying to deal with code that has to work with older and newer versions both of an API (e.g. I've had to create code that had to run on a server that only had a 1.6 runtime on it when our workstations had 1.7 JDKs installed because most all our software would run on 1.7 runtimes).
And oh, not everyone has access to an IDE where you can just click to another file. Especially when working on servers you're often restricted to a command line and a text editor.

Comment: This is no argument. The clean solution would be to reproduce the server environment locally. This way Eclipse would tell you that your used library is not compatible with your workstations JDK.

Comment: @user6444340 you obviously have never worked in the industry and don't know how things work in the real world. Just because you think that in a perfect world something should work in some way doesn't mean it does, let alone that the real world is in any way perfect. Get over your "holier than thou" attitude which is so common among youngsters with a little bit of academic theory but no practical experience.

Comment: I agree that @since makes sense for libraries. And I am working in the industry. Switching your workstations JDK version should be no big magic I guess. And reproducing a production server locally should be the first thing if you dont want to deliver buggy software. I am talking about quality.

Comment: In addition not every library is consistently using the @since tag. And this is the hard real world ;-)